# CMake: How to compile C on Windows with clang and lld with MinGW-w64 runtime

Tags: c, cmake, clang, llvm, mingw-w64

I'm building a LLVM environment on Windows that can work without Microsoft compiler and SDK and without GCC compiler or GNU linker, only LLVM ([the official build](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-12.0.0/LLVM-12.0.0-win32.exe)) and MinGW-w64 runtime.
When compiling this C program with `clang` compiler and `lld` linker, and with `x86_64-windows-gnu` target (MinGW-w64 runtime), it works:

```
> type c1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello 1\n");
    return 0;
}

> clang c1.c -target x86_64-windows-gnu -fuse-ld=lld -o c1.exe

> c1
hello 1
```

How to achieve the same with CMake? Is there a high level option for CMake to set these flags automatically? Or, when trying to set these flags manually (with `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`) looks like that it confuses CMake and it still passes some Visual C++ style flags (like `/subsystem:console`) during linking:

```
> type CMakeLists.txt
project (P1 C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -target x86_64-windows-gnu -fuse-ld=lld")
add_executable (c1 c1.c)

> cmake -G Ninja -B build -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/build

> cmake --build build
[2/2] Linking C executable c1.exe
FAILED: c1.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang.exe -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -g -Xclang -gcodeview -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd -target x86_64-windows-gnu -fuse-ld=lld  -Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/c1.dir/c1.c.obj -o c1.exe -Xlinker /implib:c1.lib -Xlinker /pdb:c1.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames && cd ."
lld: error: unable to find library -loldnames
clang: error: linker command failed with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation on toolchains here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-using-clang

Since you're overriding the default Clang target, CMake needs to know about this *during* compiler detection. By the time you're in the CMakeLists.txt, it is too late. The following `clang-x86_64_windows_gnu.cmake` toolchain file might work (I can't test it without replicating your environment):

```cmake
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-windows-gnu)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
```

Then your CMakeLists.txt was wrong, it should be:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(P1 LANGUAGES C)

add_executable(c1 c1.c)
```

Notice the order of the `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` commands. They should **always** be the first two lines in your CMakeLists.txt, in that order.

Comment: "By the time you're in the CMakeLists.txt, it is too late" - Strictly speaking, it is NOT "too late" in `CMakeLists.txt` to set toolchain-related parameters. A toolchain is activated only at the first `project()` call. It is even possible to specify `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` in the `CMakeLists.txt` instead of the command line. The reason of creating a toolchain is because of auxiliary CMake projects could be created during configuring the main one. Only the main project could see variables from `CMakeLists.txt`, but all these projects would use `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.

Comment: Yes, the _first_ `project` call is technically the boundary, but hard-coding toolchain settings into the CMakeLists.txt is never good practice and it outright won't work if you're not the parent project. With so many caveats, it's only worth teaching new users effective practices that will work everywhere. Technically correct, but not valuable.

Comment: "it's only worth teaching new users effective practices that will work everywhere." - I totally agree with that part. I disagree with the **explanations** which are actually **wrong**. If you want to describe something as a bad approach, just say "Doing .. is bad". And either do not provide explanations at all, or provide **correct** explanations. But do not argument a bad practice with explanations which are **preliminary incorrect**.

Comment: What I said is not **wrong**, it's incomplete. By the time you're in the CMakeLists.txt, it **is** too late to work **in all cases**, such as when your project is being included via `add_subdirectory`, even if you place the `set()` calls before `project()`.

Comment: I am not sure that every project should be ready for being included with `add_subdirectory`. Moreover, if the project sets **default** `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, then given project can be perfectly be included with `add_subdirectory`: in that case, the caller is expected to bother about the toolchain selection. (Again, I agree that settings like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` should be moved into a toolchain file. But I disagree with saying, that setting a toolchain in the `CMakeLists.txt` is "too late".)

Comment: By "default" toolchain I assume you mean setting CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE as a cache variable before the call to `project()`. That would break all sorts of standard CMake behaviors, like honoring the `CXX` and `CC` environment variables for compiler selection. Your project suddenly does something very different and non-standard and isn't compatible with standard `cmake -S . -B build` flows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233944/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-tsyvarev).